# How to style with css <v-divider> <v-divider/> horizonatl in vutify

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on project vujs add vutify but I should to use   commponent.

```css
 .horizontal{
             border-color: #F4F4F4 !important;
             border-width: 2px ;
                
                /*border-width: none !important;*/
         }
```

```html
      <v-divider horizontal  class=" horizontal hidden-md-and-up" ></v-divider>
```

I have try to use this code but nothing doesn't happend.
If I try to use inspect element  on web divider display as you can see.[image]
Anyone can Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You probably run into specificity issue with your css, meaning other css is to "powerful". You can try this code below that makes it more specific targeted. Note I did changes to both the component class name and the css.

```css
.theme--light.v-divider.v-divider--horizontal {
  border-color: #F4F4F4 !important;
  border-width: 2px;
  /*border-width: none !important;*/
}
```

```html
<v-divider horizontal class="v-divider--horizontal hidden-md-and-up"></v-divider>
```